# Google Web Search API returning random result for same query string in different searches

Tags: java, json, gson, google-search-api

Hi all I am working on project in which I am using Google Web Search API for web search. It works in random fashion, it results different set of result for same query string on different searches. What would be the problem.
Please reply as soon as possible. I am filtering the result for suggestions from specific websites only.
Here is my code for WebSearch.
'

```
public Map getSearchArray(String search_key) throws Exception
{
        Reader reader = null;
        GoogleResults results = null;
        URL url = null;
        int index=0;
        int result_size=0;
        Map search_result_map = new HashMap();

        try {
            logger.info("Inside GetSearch");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i=i+4) {
                String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start="+i+"&q=";
                String charset = "UTF-8";
                url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search_key, charset));
                reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
                results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
                //logger.info("resultSize: "+results.getResponseData().getResults().size());
                //System.out.println("total"+t);
                if (results.getResponseData().getResults().size()!=0) {
                    result_size = results.getResponseData().getResults().size();
                } else {
                    result_size = 1;
                }

                for (int m = 0; m <result_size; m++)
                {
                    String a=results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getUrl();
                    System.out.println(a);
                    if(a.matches(".*food.Some-Website.*")
                                ||a.matches(".*Some-Website.*")
                                ||a.matches(".*Some-Website.*")
                                ||a.matches(".*Some-Website.*")
                    {
                        logger.info("----I----"+i+"----M----"+m);
                        String title = results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getTitle().replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
                        String url_link = results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getUrl();
                        String embeded_link = createEmbeddedLink(url_link, title, "http");
                        search_result_map.put("link_"+index, embeded_link);
                        search_result_map.put("title_"+index, title);
                        index++;
                        logger.info("Title "+title);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("No Url");
                    }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.info("Exception Thrown");
            }
        finally {
            return search_result_map;
        }
    }
```

`